# How much permgen space should i add for using 5 geoserver

Tags: geoserver

My computer is windows 7 64 bit with 4 gb ram.  I am using 5 geoserver in a single apache.  How much amount of space i should added..

Comment: Additional information regarding expected workflows, number of users, and if/how the five geoservers will interact will improve this question and make it easier to answer.

Answer (score 1):

This [page](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/container.html) suggests 128Mb - if you are having problems (and if there isn't enough you'll see them fairly fast) try doubling it until you don't.